Cannot read more than 32 bytes from serial port on Windows 10
First I am sorry to ask again a question about that serial communication thing. I read several posts here about such issues and hoped I had now an understanding how that stuff works. But seemingly I am wrong.
I am writing a simple bus monitor for my homebrew RS485 base home automation system. On the controller side everything works fine, but the Windows part doesn't work right.
My bus protocol sends packets of maximum 260 bytes with 1200Bd over the RS484 line. A packet end is reported by a small break (three character times). To track a packet should be simple:

set ReadIntervalTimeout to a value a bit greater than the pause between two regular bytes. So the timeout triggers when the interpacket gap appears.
start a thread that uses readfile to read up to 260 bytes

It works for small packets, smaller than 32 bytes. But at 32 bytes the readfile ends, so I read an incomplete packet. On the next readfile I get the rest of the packet. I could assemble both parts together, but why does it stop after 32 bytes?

The uart_init function creates a thread calling the RS485Receiver. And the RS485Receiver thread function calls uart_init function, which creates a thread calling the RS485Receiver function, and so on and on and on... That doesn't seem quite right.

I would read the first 4 bytes of the struct into RS485PacketBuffer in one read, then read the next RS485PacketBuffer->length bytes into RS485PacketBuffer->d. You might have to do that in a loop until you have all the data.

@Thorsten Erdmann, With if (!ReadFile(hComm, RS485PacketBuffer, 64/*sizeof(T_PACKET)*/, &dwRead, &osRead))  {, RS485PacketBuffer lacks a definition.  Please post the definition of RS485PacketBuffer.  A [mcve] is even better.

Perhaps, Are you using a USB serial conversion adapter? The reason may be the packet size of 64 bytes in USB full speed mode.

@Someprogrammerdude: you are right. I moved that line out of the libraries init routine which does some other stuff into the thread's routine for readability. That was nonsense. I corrected that in the first post now.

@chux-ReinstateMonica: I added the definition above. It's only a pointer to a T_PACKET structure which is "malloced" in the init routine. I wil try to produce a standalone example. It's a bit of work to extract that because the library is also used on the microcontroller side and contains the complete protocol handling.

@001: yes that would be possible but it would need the assembly of the packages from several reads. I don't loke that very much. It would also need extensive error handlich, e.g. if you missed the start of the package and then misinterpret some data bytes as packet length.

One problem with serial communication is that it's a streaming system. All data flows like a stream, without actual beginning or end of the data. Things like "messages", "packets", or boundaries doesn't really exist. That's actually why many of the low values of ASCII was used for, to add some structure to the data, telling the receiver what bytes are the header of the message, what bytes are the actual data, and when the data ends. But because the data is streaming, both sender and receiver need to use loops to transmit all the data of a single message.

@kunif: yes, I use an USB/serial adapter. But does the adapter's buffer really has an effect of the ReadFile function? I would thing when I say I want to read several hundret bytes and set the timout correctly it should read all of them.

I know that streaming thing. Therefore I added the pause between data packets. What I do not understand, why does ReadFile doesn't wait for n bytes if I say it should?

For your specific use-case, I recommend you split up the packet structure into two parts: The fixed-size header and the actual data in the message. As mentioned above, first read the header, then in a loop read the data. This is really very simple, even the reassembling of the messages... You have the exact length of the data, and you could get a pointer to the buffer to receive the data. Each time you read the data, you update the remaining length to read, and update the pointer to where in the buffer it should be placed.

@ThorstenErdmann The comment in if (!ReadFile(hComm, RS485PacketBuffer, 64/*sizeof(T_PACKET)*/, &dwRead, &osRead)) is suspicious as the sizeof(T_PACKET) is more like 260.  The naked magic number 64 deserves clarification.

Side note: Since this is rs-485, are you not using a sticky bit? (Admittedly, I've never tried this from a Windows PC and wouldn't expect for support for it with a generic USB/serial adapter.)

The problem with assembling the packet is, that without detecting the time gap between the packets I cannot find the beginning of the paket. Let's say I start my program in the middle of a packet and interpret the length byte, I will then read an invalid number of bytes. And will never find the beginning of the next packet. I have to somehow detect that the read is finished because all bytes are read or because of a timeout. But it seems ReadFile don't give that information. It quietly returns with no error with or without timeout. I have no idea how to solve this.

What is a sticky bit regarding RS485? I use a USB to RS485 adapter which showas up as a serial port.

if I set ReadIntervalTimeout to zero and ReadTotalTimeoutConstant to 500ms i get a complete package from ReadFile. But then I miss the next paket if it comes closely to the first. So ReadFile CAN read more than 32 bytes in one chunk. Why doesn't it work with the interval timeout?

OK, evidently it is not always done this way and you aren't doing so. When I've worked on rs485. a sticky bit was used in the place a parity bit might otherwise be. It was used to flag the beginning of a message. On transmission the code changed the value to use before the transmission of the first byte and back afterwards. Receivers scanned for this to detect beginning of message. UARTs included support (of varying qualities) for operating this way.

Interesting: if I set the Interval timeout to a value greater that 280ms, which is the length of 32 bytes at 1200Bd I get 64 bytes back. It seems the interval timeout is to the timeout for two subsequent bytes but the timeout from the first byte!

@Thorsten Erdmann , A long time ago, I used a serial port with a 16550 compatible south bridge, rather than the current USB-to-serial converter. At that time, the EV_RXCHAR event was sometimes notified every 8 bytes. It was probably operating in units of the FIFO buffer threshold. There may be some hardware or protocol constraint that affects this processing unit, and the USB hardware/protocol packet size may be one such constraint.

What kind of equipment is the program supposed to connect to? Will it just send packets onto the serial bus even if no-one is connected to it? There's no kind of synchronization message that can be sent from your end to tell the device to restart the stream of packets or similar?

It is a self developed bus system were several microcontroller based dimmers, lightswitches and sensors connected. The above application at the moment should only read and display the data pakets. And the only indication when a ticket starts and ends is the gap between the data flow.

@ThorstenErdmann Correctly designed UART protocols use "sync bytes" for this very reason. Some byte sequence unlikely to appear in the data itself, like 0x55 + 0xAA or whatever.

"Correctly designed" is relative. If you use SYNC bytes you cannot transfer binary data without escaping the SYNC bytes. That makes the protocol much more complicated. And using a timeout as a protocol parameter seems not wrong to me.

But I think I have to give up. I now tried to read the serial data byte per byte and even then I notice irregular delays between the reception of consecutive bytes, so that I cannot detect the gap clearly. It seems such "realtime" processing of data is not possible on modern OSes anymore. I think I build a microcontroller based adapter which handles the bus protocol and converts it to an ASCII based listing which is then transfered via a second UART or even network to the PC.

Regarding the update: the timeout settings in Windows were never reliable. Windows often has a hard time keeping up with a serial port. And in addition, most USB-to-RS232 adapters are trash and you may have to tweak the drivers manually. This is for example the case with many solutions based on FTDI chips, which come with drivers that like to bug out with every single Windows update. So don't be so sure this is a problem created on your side.

It seems that it is not possible on Windows to securely use the timeout settings. Especially the ReadIntervalTimeout does not work as expected. It returns after 32 Bytes, regardless if there are more byte coming. Also I cannot read the complete data block of max. 260 bytes in one piece. Even if I set the ReadTotalTimeoutConstant to very long the WaitForSingleObject function returns before the wanted number of bytes are read and you have to start a new ReadFile.
The solution is now, to ignore all this timeout stuff and read first the four byte header which contains the length field and the read the rest of the data using this length information. This is the solution suggested by "Some programmer dude".
The below code kind of works but because of not detecting the interpacket gaps by timeout it can come to reading a wrong amount of data if the header is corrupted, e.g. by bus collisions or if you start the program during transmission.
I completely rewrote the code so now it is a completely usable code.
/*
 *  Test program for reading homenet packets from RS485 bus via USB-to-RS485 adapter
 *
 *  Restrictions:
 *     - program do not use timeouts to detect packets, so it may misinterpret data under heavy bus load
 *     - in case of transmission errors or bus collisions the packet header may be corrupted and therefor a false length
 *       information is read. This may lead to misread next packets
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>

#define BAUDRATE 1200   // RS485 bus soeed

struct HN_PACKET
{
    uint8_t dest;
    uint8_t src;
    uint8_t socket;
    uint8_t length;
    uint8_t d[256];
} rcvbuffer;

HN_PACKET RS485PacketBuffer;

/*
 *  dump packet to console 
 */
void PrintPacket(HN_PACKET *packet)
{
    DWORD adr = 0;
    DWORD i;
    printf("\nSrc: %u, dest: %u, socket:%u, length: %u:", packet->src, packet->dest, packet->socket, packet->length);
    if (!packet->dest)
    {
        packet->d[packet->length] = 0; // for security put a 0-character at the end of the packet
        printf(" DEBUGMSG : %s", packet->d);
    }
    do
    {
        printf("\n  ");
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            if (adr + i < packet->length) printf(" %02x", packet->d[adr+i]);
            else printf("   ");
        }
        printf("  ");
        for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        {
            if (adr + i < packet->length) putchar(isprint(packet->d[adr+i])?packet->d[adr+i]:'.');
        }
        adr += 16;
    } while (adr < packet->length);
    printf("\n");
}

// Opens the specified serial port, configures its timeouts, and sets its
// baud rate.  Returns a handle on success, or INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE on failure.
HANDLE uart_init(LPCWSTR szPortName, uint32_t baud_rate)
{
    HANDLE hComm;

    hComm = CreateFile(szPortName,
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,//access ( read and write)
        0,    //(share) 0:cannot share the COM port                        
        0,    //security  (None)                
        OPEN_EXISTING,// creation : open_existing
        FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,// we want overlapped operation
        0// no templates file for COM port...
    );

    if (hComm == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return hComm;

    DCB dcb = { 0 };
    dcb.DCBlength = sizeof(DCB);
    if (!GetCommState(hComm, &dcb))
    {
        printf("CSerialCommHelper : Failed to Get Comm State Reason: %d\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hComm);
        return NULL;
    }
    dcb.BaudRate = baud_rate;
    dcb.ByteSize = 8;
    dcb.Parity = NOPARITY;
    dcb.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    if (!SetCommState(hComm, &dcb))
    {
        printf("CSerialCommHelper : Failed to Set Comm State Reason: %d\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hComm);
        return NULL;
    }
    SetCommMask(hComm, EV_RXCHAR);

    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;
    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = MAXDWORD;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = MAXDWORD;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 7000;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 0;
    if (!SetCommTimeouts(hComm, &timeouts))
    {
        printf("CSerialCommHelper :  Error setting time-outs. %d\n", GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(hComm);
        return NULL;
    }
    return hComm;
}


/*
 * Serial data receive thread
 * Thread is started from uartInit function
 */
unsigned int __stdcall RS485Receiver(void* data)
//int SerialThreadFn(HANDLE m_hCommPort)
{
    HANDLE hComm;

    DWORD dwBytes; // number of bytes read
    DWORD dwRead;                // number of bytes read per ReadFile
    DWORD dwRes;                 // result for WaitForSingleObject
    BOOL fWaitingOnRead = FALSE; // flag for pending data reception
    OVERLAPPED osReader = { 0 }; // overlapped structure
    char* buffer = (char*)&RS485PacketBuffer; // pointer to packet buffer

    puts("Serial Thread started");
    if (hComm = uart_init((LPCWSTR)data, 1200))
    {

        // Create the overlapped event. Must be closed before exiting
        // to avoid a handle leak.
        osReader.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
        if (osReader.hEvent == NULL)
        {
            // Error creating overlapped event; abort.
            puts("Error creating overlapped event");
            CloseHandle(hComm);
            return 1;
        }

        dwBytes = 0;
        while (1)
        {
            if (!fWaitingOnRead)
            {
                // Issue read operation.
                if (!ReadFile(hComm, (char*)&RS485PacketBuffer + dwBytes, (dwBytes<4) ? 4 : RS485PacketBuffer.length + 1, &dwRead, &osReader))
                {
                    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) // read not delayed ?
                        // Error in communications; report it.
                        printf("Communication error\n");
                    else
                        fWaitingOnRead = TRUE;
                }
                else
                {
                    // read completed immediately
                    if (dwRead)
                    {
                        dwBytes += dwRead;
                        if (dwBytes > RS485PacketBuffer.length + 4U)
                        {
                            PrintPacket(&RS485PacketBuffer);
                            dwBytes = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // packet timeout, restart reading header
                        dwBytes = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (fWaitingOnRead)
            {
                dwRes = WaitForSingleObject(osReader.hEvent, INFINITE);
                switch (dwRes)
                {
                    // Read completed.
                case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                    if (!GetOverlappedResult(hComm, &osReader, &dwRead, FALSE))
                        // Error in communications; report it.
                        printf("Communication error\n");
                    else
                    {
                        if (dwRead)
                        {
                            // Read completed successfully.
                            dwBytes += dwRead;
                            if (dwBytes > RS485PacketBuffer.length + 4U)
                            {
                                PrintPacket(&RS485PacketBuffer);
                                dwBytes = 0;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // packet timeout, restart reading header
                            dwBytes = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
                    break;
                case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                    // Operation isn't complete yet. fWaitingOnRead flag isn't
                    // changed since I'll loop back around, and I don't want
                    // to issue another read until the first one finishes.
                    //
                    // This is a good time to do some background work.
                    puts("Waittimeout");
                    break;
                default:
                    // Error in the WaitForSingleObject; abort.
                    // This indicates a problem with the OVERLAPPED structure's
                    // event handle.
                    puts("Error");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(osReader.hEvent);
        CloseHandle(hComm);
        // return dwRead;
    }
    puts("Serial Thread stopped");
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    // Choose the serial port name.
    LPCWSTR device = L"\\\\.\\COM4";

    // Choose the baud rate (bits per second).  This does not matter if you are
    // connecting to the SMC over USB.  If you are connecting via the TX and RX
    // lines, this should match the baud rate in the SMC G2's serial settings.

    _beginthreadex(0, 0, &RS485Receiver, (void *)device, 0, 0);
    puts("Press any key to stop");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

